# git command to check for code changes in the git repo and use of it in the Batch file

Tags: git, batch-file

I am writing a batch file for Build auto server, which checks for any changes in the git repository and if there is it will pull the changes from the repo to my workspace and build the files. However I am not sure of which commands to use or the correct method to use it .

Comment: What have you tried already? StackOverflow is not a "do the work for you" board, it is for helping you complete what you've started.

Answer (score 0):

On linux put `git pull origin master && yourBuildCommandsHere` in a bash script and create a cronjob that runs this script every x minutes.

On windows you can schedule the script with AT commands.. http://www.computerhope.com/at.htm